# Tensorflow - Is there a way to separate tf.data.Dataset by label?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I do know that I can separate my data by their label before I load them into my network. Let's say there are 3 classes, with labels 0,1,2. I can do it by:

```
dataset1 = tf.data.TextLineDataset(train_csv_file1).map(_parse_csv_train)
dataset2 = tf.data.TextLineDataset(train_csv_file2).map(_parse_csv_train)
dataset3 = tf.data.TextLineDataset(train_csv_file3).map(_parse_csv_train)
```

I am just curious about the following:

Suppose we have the dataset:

```
dataset = tf.data.TextLineDataset(train_csv_file).map(_parse_csv_train)
```

which contains all the data from the 3 classes,

**is there a way to call some function like** `dataset.selectDataByLabel(label=="2")` [this is a made-up function] **so that I can divide the dataset into 3 parts according to their labels?**

Comment: Are you asking about `filter(predicate` ? [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#filter)

Comment: Thank you for telling me this filter() function, but I didn't figure out how to use it properly. In fact, the dataset variable is in the form image, label. How can I element-wise filter the dataset according to their labels?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So finally I chose to separate the files by csvs, i.e. generate csvs that each contains data from only one class. This might not be a perfect solution when there are too many classes, but in my case there are only 5 classes so it doesn't matter.